# Area under this chaotic function. Is it possible.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

So there is this function f defined by
f (x) = 1 if x is rational and
f (x) = 0 if x is irrational.

Is it possible to calculate the area under f(x) in the interval [0, 1]? If it exists. I know that using Riemann Integral would fail though, can we use the Legesgue Integral to do it? If so, how?

P.S. This question is originally from a Hong Kong forum LIHKG. Why would a forum post a mathematics question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: your function is equal to the function that is constantly zero almost everywhere with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Added: If $f$ and $g$ are both Lebesgue measurable, integrable functions and are equal almost everywhere with respect to Lebesgue measure then $$\int f d\mu = \int g d\mu,$$
where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: So since the Lebesgue measure is 0 (Constant Function), the Lebesgue Integration of this Indicator Function f(x)(Because it is indicating if x is in $\mathbb{Q}$ $\bigcap$ [0, 1]) is $\mu$(f(x)) = 0. Is it right?

Comment: @KGSH bteam Mine Team Beast O_ Sorry, I’m not sure I follow your argument. I will add a few details.

Comment: Okay. Since f(x) is equal to the function g(x)=0 at almost everywhere, the Lebesgue measure is the same. Then $\mu$(f(x)) = 0 and the Lebesgue Integration $\int1_Q d\mu = \mu(f(x)) = 0$ ? (Wikipedia for Indicator Functions)

Comment: @ KGSH bteam Mine Team Beast O_ I think you’ve got it, but I’d write it a bit differently. Since, $1_Q = 0$ almost everywhere, $$\int_{[0,1]} 1_Q d\mu = \int_{[0,1]} 0 d\mu= 0.$$

Comment: Oh yes I get it. Thanks a lot.